# Android, метод getFilter(), интерфейса Filterable, в Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Ситуация такая, использую `Filterable`, во время поиска, сначала использовал `Activity`, но затем понадобилось использовать фрагмент. Не буду вдаваться в структуру кода, но вызов метода происходит в кастомном адаптере.

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return ((MainActivity) mContext).new ListFilter();
}
```

Вот этот код расположен в адаптере, когда использую `Activity`, но если я использую фрагмент, то не могу понять как мне переделать этот метод, чтобы он корректно работал. А да, `ListFilter()` это `inner` класс, который наследуется от `Filter`. Как мне реализовать подобный метод в фрагменте?

Comment: так в чем проблема, контекст подцепить не можете?

Comment: Да как я только этот контекст не подставлял))